# Python Rename matching values in column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with a name column. I want to edit the string for those values that are repeated.

Example:

```
  name
J. Doe
J. Doe
J. Doe
```

Expected output

```
    name
  J. Doe
J. Doe 1
J. Doe 2
```

Comment: please format the text in your question appropriately, either as formatted text like above or (better) as pandas dataframe as this enables direct copy pasting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC, you can use:

```
num = df.groupby('name').cumcount()
df.loc[num.ne(0), 'name'] += ' '+num.astype(str)
```

output:

```
       name
0    J. Doe
1  J. Doe 1
2  J. Doe 2
```

used input:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'name': ['J. Doe', 'J. Doe', 'J. Doe']})
```